# accessing other tab from one window

Tags: javascript, html

How does the browser treat multiple tab? Are they completely separate entity where no interaction is possible?  I understand the sandbox concept of the browser and other security concerns but is it possible for a webpage to interact with another tab in the browser?

Basically my question is: If a user loads one webpage in a new tab, is there some way to access information of other tab which is already opened or will be opened after?

I have one concept of an application which needs to know about the other tab already opened or opened after my conceptual webpage but I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: What does your application do?  Could web services be used instead?

Comment: I think it might be possible if one of the tabs is related to the other (parent/child), like pop-ups do. But unrelated tabs are probably way off-limits. Unless you build a browser extension.

Comment: Just imagine a web page with malicious code starting collecting all the information from your other opened tabs...

Comment: @Justin: Correct me if I am wrong since I am relatively new to web. Web service can be used if the desired webpage provides their web API, right?

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades It depends how you have it setup.  For instance, there can be stand-alone web services that a web page can interact with via AJAX.  There is also the concept of web methods.  You can access them via AJAX but they belong to a specific page.  the web methods are specific to ASP.NET as far as I know.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades What do you want to do exactly? Is the page in the other tab from another domain?

Comment: @ZippyV: Yes, The desired tab will be in different domain and I think based on the answer and suggestion, this might not be possible.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades Indeed, that's not possible because of security issues.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades If you can provide more information as to WHAT you are doing, we can possibly make suggestions as to what CAN be done to get the desired effect.

Comment: @Justin : Thanks for the concern. I was clearing some concepts for an idea which is still hazy in my mind. I am still thinking about the approach right now and not clear myself. I will post on SO if I can definitely find the direction. Thanks for the answer Justin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, this isn't possible.  The browser wouldn't allow you to manipulate the browser's lower functions in a regular environment.  It would ignore it or show a security error come up.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to do that, except when both documents are written to communicate with each other (Like in *vBulletin* new windows). The only way to access tabs is writing Add-Ons for the browser.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access other tabs on the client-side.

However, I can imagine a scenario in which this could be done server side. Have the user log in to your site on both tabs and use something like sockets to pass data back and forth from one tab to the other using the server as a middle-man.

Answer (score 1):

If both pages are from the same domain, you can use cookies or, in HTML5, local storage.

Answer (score 1):

If you own the other tabs, you can *broadcast* to other tabs, and other tabs can *broadcast* back to your tab, creating a practical communication channel among them.

This is called [Inter-window messaging](http://bens.me.uk/2013/localstorage-inter-window-messaging), and it uses `LocalStorage`.

---

To simply check if you are the active tab, use `$(window).blur( ... )`, or a similar technique using a library of your choice.